# Magento 2 Category Description not showing

Tags: magento2, category

I have a Magento 2 store and I am trying to get the category descriptions to be visable. I am not sure when I type in text to the category admin in the description text box and click save, clear cache it does not show? So I found this file desc_main_column.phtml which I believe contains the code to show a category description. So I tried to var_dump the

```
var_dump($this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_description, 'description') );
```

However it shows not show any data. So I am not sure why and more importantly how to get the below code to show the category description content.

```
<?php
    $_category_desc = $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data')->getConfig('porto_settings/category/category_description');
?>
<?php if ($_category_desc == "main_column" && $_description = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
   <div class="category-description">
       <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_description, 'description') ?>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you verify that, category description save in admin?

Comment: yes I have confirmed that the description is being saved in the description box in the category admin

Comment: I'd be surprised if this wasn't an issue of scope. Change the store view in the admin panel to "Store View: Default Store View" or equivalent. Then set everything to use the default (or just enter the information here).